# How to make Gulp complete one task, and only then start the next one

Tags: javascript, gulp, minify

I've set up some simple Gulp tasks to process my CSS files.

The tasks are put together in one 'master' task:

`gulp.task('process-css', ['concatCSS', 'minifyCSS', 'renameCSS']);`

Just for reference, the definition of the concrete tasks follows:

```
gulp.task('minifyCSS', function() {
    return gulp.src('themes/my_theme/css/dist/*.css')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(minifyCSS())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('themes/my_theme/css/dist/'));
});

gulp.task('concatCSS', function() {

    var files = [
        'themes/rubbish_taxi/css/bootstrap.css',
        'themes/rubbish_taxi/css/custom.css',
        'themes/rubbish_taxi/css/responsive.css',
        'themes/rubbish_taxi/css/jquery.fancybox.css'
    ];

    return gulp.src(files)
        .pipe(concat("bundle.css"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('themes/my_theme/css/dist/'));
});

gulp.task('renameCSS', function() {
    gulp.src('themes/my_theme/css/dist/bundle.css')
        .pipe(rename(function(path) {
            path.basename += ".min";
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("themes/my_theme/css/"));
});
```

The tasks complete without an error, but the problem is that `minifyCSS` does not minify the source file. An unminified version of the files is saved as `bundle.min.css`. I believe that the reason is that `minifyCSS` runs before `concatCSS` completed.

How can I make the tasks be executed synchronously?
Is my only option to specify which tasks should be executed before a give task like this:

`gulp.task('minifyCSS', ['concatCSS'], function() {..}` ?

It worked when I set it this way, but I wanted to avoid this to make code more readable.

Comment: why are you splitting minification concatenation and renaming across separate tasks? Gulp works best when you pipe them all together in a single task (to avoid writing and then rereading).

Comment: @zzzzBov, can I be sure that tasks piped in one function be executed synchronously to avoid a similar problem. As @deefour noted below `gulp.task('minifyCSS', ['concatCSS'], function() {..} ` is  how we tell gulp that one task depends on the other being completed.

Answer (score 2):

> gulp.task('minifyCSS', ['concatCSS'], function() {..} ?
>
> It worked when I set it this way, but I wanted to avoid this to make code more readable.

More readable how? You're stating that `minifyCSS` is dependent on `concatCSS`. The line of code I quoted above is how you explain this dependency to gulp.

The alternative is to use something like [run-sequence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence), but I think avoiding functionality built into the tool to solve the exact problem you're facing isn't justified by the desire for a subjective improvement in readability.

Comment: So I guess the answer is to use the notation I tried to avoid (avoid unreasonably, agreed).